# Bash script exporting variables with if function

Tags: linux, bash

I got some not working script about checking if the variable is empty, and based on this create the next variable and export it.

```
export VARIABLE=macmac123

if [ -z "$VARIBLE" ]
then 
      unset $VAR2 
else 
      export VAR2="test"
fi
```

Next I run this script ./script.sh and then running echo $VAR2 doesn't show anything. Any ideas? I can't change the whole script, because I need this, but it doesn't export anything into environmental variables.

Comment: You don't use `$` when referring to the variable with `unset`

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child processes. Changing variables in the script doesn't affect the parent process.

Comment: You need to use `source scriptname` to run the script in the current shell process to make it change its variables.

Comment: In addition you need to fix up the typo: `"$VARIBLE"` -> `"$VARIABLE"`

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts are executed in a subshell. If you want the variables in the current shell you have to `source` the script like: `source script.sh` or `. script.sh` (dot is an alias for `source`).

Comment: It's the other way around: `source` is a synonym for `.` -- "dot" was invented first in the Bourne shell.